# Match two data frames by substring in python

Tags: python, pandas, performance, optimization, string-matching

I have two big data frames (1000s of rows), and I need to match them by substring, for example:

df1:

```
Id    Title
1     The house of pump
2     Where is Andijan
3     The Joker
4     Good bars in Andijan
5     What a beautiful house
```

df2:

```
Keyword
house
andijan
joker
```

And the expected output is:

```
Id    Title                    Keyword
1     The house of pump        house
2     Where is Andijan         andijan
3     The Joker                joker
4     Good bars in Andijan     andijan
5     What a beautiful house   house
```

Now, I've sort of written a very non-efficient way to match it, but for the actual size of the data frames it runs for an extremely long time:

```
for keyword in df2.to_dict(orient='records'):
    df1['keyword'] = np.where(creative_df['title'].str.contains(keyword['keyword']), keyword['keyword'], df1['keyword'])
```

Now, I'm sure there's a more pandas-friendy and efficient way to do the same, and also have it run in a reasonable time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try `findall`

```
import re
df1['new'] = df1.Title.str.findall('|'.join(df2.Keyword.tolist()),flags= re.IGNORECASE).str[0]
df1
   Id                   Title      new
0   1       The house of pump    house
1   2        Where is Andijan  Andijan
2   3               The Joker    Joker
3   4    Good bars in Andijan  Andijan
4   5  What a beautiful house    house
```

Comment: Nice. I believe in this case we can resign from ".tolist()" as 'join' will give the same result for pandas series.

Comment: As far as nice pandas syntax, I like this solution! However, as far as performance goes, this solution is still running for quite some time without completing it. For reference's sake, there are about 65000 keywords. Any idea how to make it more efficient?

Comment: I eventually went with this solution. For a more efficient runtime, I reduced the keyword count to ~1000 and ran my process in batches. This is probably the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Developing @BENY's solution a little further in order to be able to get multiple keywords per title:

```py
regex = '|'.join(keywords['Keyword'])
keywords = df['Title'].str.findall(regex, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
keywords_exploded = pd.DataFrame(keywords.explode().dropna())
df.merge(keywords_exploded, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```